# Multiple relations (pivot) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pivot

I have a problem with related models.

There are three models. User, PostType (music, animals) and Post.

A user can select the posttypes he wants to see. So I created a pivot-table posttype_user. 
Now I can save the selected postTypes binded to a user.

```
// User model
    public function postTypes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(PostType::class);
    }

// PostType model
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

The Post model has a foreign key with postType_id. And this relationships in the models:

```
// Post model
    public function postType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PostType::class);
    }

// PostType model
    public function post()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
```

Now I want to receive all Posts (of the selected posTypes) from the current user (Auth::user()).

But I don't know how. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You should start from reading https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
Post::whereHas('postType', function($q) {
        $q->whereHas('users', function($q) {
            $q->where('id', auth()->id());
        });
    })->get();
```

Or you can do this:

```
$postTypeIds = auth()->user()->postTypes()->pluck('id');
$posts = Post::whereIn('post_type_id', $postTypeIds)->get();
```